# How can to scale svg images automatically in javafx 8?

Tags: java, svg, javafx, javafx-8

I have drawn an image in inkscape.I can see the option to export it as javafx script file i.e .fx. But as per my knowledge .fx is obsolete now in javafx 8.So it is not recommend to use it.I can use the svg images using the batik where I have to convert them to javafx image format then I can set it to imageview .I want this image to be scaled automatically when ever i moved my **application to bigger resolution**.Any help on this will be appreciated .

My custom Transcoder Code

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.InputStream;

```
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;

import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderException;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderInput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderOutput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.ImageTranscoder;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.PNGTranscoder;

class MyTranscoder extends ImageTranscoder {

  private BufferedImage image = null;
  private InputStream url;

  MyTranscoder(InputStream url) {

    this.url = url;
  }

  @Override
  public BufferedImage createImage(int w, int h) {
    image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    return image;
  }

  @Override
  public void writeImage(BufferedImage img, TranscoderOutput out) {
  }

  public BufferedImage getImage() {
    return image;
  }

  public Image getJavafxCompatibleImage(int width, int height) {
    this.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, (float) width);
    this.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT, (float) height);
    TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(url);
    try {
      this.transcode(input, null);
    } catch (TranscoderException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedImage bimage = this.getImage();
    WritableImage wimage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bimage, null);
    return wimage;
  }

}
```